# Specific JSON formatting for Yahoo DataX in C#

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on a project to integrate with yahoo, and they're requiring that the JSON file I send over is in a format of: each object in the list be in a single row, with no starting/ending "[]" and no commas.

```
{"urn": "e12b6e8135d73...","att": {"id": "MyId","val": 2607}}
{"urn": "6c6355c27642e...","att": {"id": "MyId","val": 2607}}
{"urn": "d415821e454c7...","att": {"id": "MyId","val": 2607}}
```

Because these files are multi million objects large, I'm using a TextWriter and JsonSerializer to build the file.

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(dataFileLocation))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
            }
```

I know I can do a char replacement and newline after each object after building the file, but I feel like that would be much more work than needed and isn't very flexible for any changes that may come down the road.

I'm using NewtonSoft for my JSON manipulation, but I can use something else if something else has a formatter that does this specific format. I've looked for other options, but couldn't find anything. So either I'm blind or this has to be done a custom way.

Comment: What is data? Where is code that creates it?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Yahoo may not be on the forefront of technology like it once was, but requiring invalid JSON and specific formatting is ridiculous, even for them.

Comment: @madreflection, Yup I have a contact at Yahoo and this is the example they gave. And in https://developer.yahooinc.com/datax/guide/user-aud-top/formatting-rules/ they say: "Each unit of data must be represented as a single line of input in the final payload."

Comment: This section is more relevant to the actual issue and to actually display the format. https://developer.yahooinc.com/datax/guide/user-aud-top/post-audience/#representation-example-3-upload-a-score-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a little easier than I thought, and this just hit me... The answer is:

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(dataFileLocation))
            {
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
            }
```